# How to send multiple orders to binance at incrementally decreasing prices in python using FOR loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, binance

I am using python-binance to connect to binance cryptocurrency exchange. I am able to send orders simply using this code:

```
client.create_margin_order(
                symbol =           'BTCUSDT',
                side =             Client.SIDE_BUY,
                type =             Client.ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
                timeInForce =      Client.TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                quantity =         100,
                price =            10000
                recvWindow =       5000,
                timestamp =        time.time_ns())
```

I am able to get a FOR loop to send the correct number of orders but i need each order in the range to send an order at 5% below the last order. How can I achieve this?

My current idea looks like this, however it sends all 10 orders at 5% below the bid price as opposed to 5% below each previous order.

```
for x in range(10):
            client.create_margin_order(
                symbol =           'BTCUSDT',
                side =             Client.SIDE_BUY,
                type =             Client.ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
                timeInForce =      Client.TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                quantity =         100,
                price =            d.Decimal(bidprice) * d.Decimal(0.95), #????????
                recvWindow =       5000,
                timestamp =        time.time_ns())
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to update the price after the API call.

```
price=10000
for x in range(10):
    print(price)
    price *= .95
```

Output

```
10000
9500.0
9025.0
8573.75
8145.0625
7737.809375
7350.918906249999
6983.372960937499
6634.204312890623
6302.494097246092
```